# Evaluating the sum $\lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{k=t}^{\infty} f(k)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to find out what conditions make the expression below hold.

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{k=t}^{\infty} f(k) = 0$$

So I thought $\lim_{t \to \infty}\sum_{k=t}^{\infty} f(k) = \lim_{t \to \infty}\sum_{k=t}^{t} f(k) = \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) $

Then I would conjecture that the series converges to zero if and only if the function $f(t)$ converges to zero. Would my conjecture here would be correct?

Any help/tip would be appreciated.

Comment: "if and only if the function $f(t)$ converges to zero" This is not true. Take $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$. Then $\sum_{k=t}^\infty f(k)$ diverges to infinity for any $t\geq 1$. Your argument starting with "So I thought" is unfortunately totally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Tail estimation" is the idea that the sum of a series over $n$, starting from a large index $N$, can be made arbitrarily small IF the series over $n$ converges in the first place. That is to say, if

$$\Big|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\Big| < \infty$$

then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an index $N$ such that

$$\Big|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n\Big| < \varepsilon.$$

The proof is actually very simple; let $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n$ and let $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. Then by definition, $S_N \to S$ as $N \to \infty$, and therefore

$$|S - S_N| = \Big|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n\Big|$$

must go to zero with $N$.

This idea seems to be exactly what you are describing in your question, so I would presume the answer is "it can be done exactly when the sum converges in the first place".